# different views for setting class path for java program

Tags: java, path, environment-variables, classpath

I am trying to run my simple java program via command prompt. While compiling the code there is no error. But every time I execute the program, I get the same error,

```
C:\Users\anapi>javac simple.java

C:\Users\anapi>java Simple.class
Error: Could not find or load main class Simple.class
C:\Users\anapi>java -cp . Simple.class
Error: Could not find or load main class Simple.class
```

I searched in net for the solution, and there are many solutions provided. But none of them worked for me. So I've posted here for the help. I know the problem is due to class path and I tried the possible solutions too but none of them worked. Please check my JAVA configurations details.

```
C:\Users\anapi>java -version
java version "1.8.0_101"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_101-b13)
Java HotSpot(TM) Client VM (build 25.101-b13, mixed mode)

C:\Users\anapi>javac -version
javac 1.8.0_101

C:\Users\anapi>echo %JAVA_HOME%
C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_101

C:\Users\anapi>echo %PATH%
C:\ProgramData\Oracle\Java\javapath;C:\Windows\system32;C:\Windows;C:\Windows\System32\Wbem;C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_101\bin;C:\Program Files\Java\jre1.8.0_101\bin

C:\Users\anapi>echo %CLASSPATH%
.C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_101\bin;
```

My code:

```
  class Simple{  
        public static void main(String args[]){  
         System.out.println("Hello Java");  
        }  
    }
```

Please help me I am badly stuck in this problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the command as ::

```
C:\Users\anapi>java Simple
```

Also note that if you are using Eclipse and want to compile and execute your code from command prompt then follow the following steps::

1. Suppose your java file is simple.java inside [*C:\Users\anapi\workspace\test*],

for compiling the code ::

```
C:\Users\anapi\workspace\test>javac C:\Users\anapi\workspace\test\src\test\simple.java
```

and for executing the code ::

```
C:\Users\anapi\workspace\test>java -cp bin test.Simple
```

You can get the class path of the source file by running the program in debug mode. After that, in the upper left tab [Debug], right click on your terminated program and go to Properties. There in the Command Line box you can see the classpath. Paste the classpath with java command in command prompt.

```
C:\Users\anapi>java -classpath C:\Users\anapi\workspace\FirstProject\bin test.HelloWorld
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Write this instead:

```
C:\Users\anapi>java Simple
```

without the ".class"